# All images and containers disappeared after host kernel downgrade

Tags: package-management, docker, deb

On the host machine was installed kernel 3.16. After installation the kernel 3.14 via deb package I lost all docker images and containers. Output of commands `docker images` and `docker ps -a` are empty.

Is this normal behavior for docker?

Comment: This sounds more like a packaging issue than a docker issue.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself. It may be useful someone.

Docker used storage driver "aufs" on the old kernel. Therefore the module "aufs.ko" must be loaded. In the new kernel support aufs was not be enabled and docker began to use storage driver "devicemapper".